# Db2 - load LOB data returns error SQL3025N A parameter specifying a filename or path is not valid

Tags: db2, export, db2-luw, load

I would like to learn how to load LOB data from files. I have a table with two columns:

```
ID INTEGER
DATA CLOB
```

I can normaly export data with:

```
export to c:\data\data.txt of del lobs to c:\data\ modified by coldel@ select * from mytab
```

Now I would like to import back the same data:

```
load client from c:\data\data.txt of del lobs from c:\data\ modified by coldel@ replace into mytab
```

but I get error "SQL3025N  A parameter specifying a filename or path is not valid."

Strange error. I have the same file paths using load as export.

How to solve the problem with load?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you run `load client`, the LOB files are still expected to be on the server.